# Particular solution to 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE:
$$
y''(x)+\left(\frac{a}{x}+\frac{ab}{x^2}\right)y(x)=\frac{ab}{x^2}e^{cx},
$$
where $a,c>0$ and $b<0$ are constants.

The homogeneous equation is easy to solve: its solution is expressible through the Bessel functions $J_m(x)$ and $N_m(x)$. The only problem is to find any particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation. Any suggestions? I tried to get rid of the exponential function by trying $y(x)=e^{cx}g(x)$ for some $g(x)$. This led to the equation:
$$
g''(x)+2cg'(x)+\left(\frac{a}{x}+\frac{ab}{x^2}+c^2\right)g(x)=\frac{ab}{x^2},
$$
which I am not sure how to solve. Any advise?

Comment: the solution containes the Bessel function

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what does the solution look like though?

Comment: Variation of parameters would give it to you in integral from, it might be the only way.